# How to connect to a network drive from Azure Data Factory Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I was successfully able to connect to my local machine using File System Linked Service. But now, when I am trying to access a folder from a network drive using a similar approach, I am unable to proceed. Please can anyone tell me where am I going wrong ?

The below is the working version when connected from my local machine.

```
{
    "name": "Test_FileSystem",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
    "properties": {
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "FileServer",
        "typeProperties": {
            "host": "D:\\AZURE_FS",
            "userId": "<xxx@org.com>",
            "encryptedCredential": "eyJDcmVkZW50aWFsSWQiOiI0ZDYwMWI1Yi02YmI3LTRlN2YtOTBmYi0xNmIzZjI1MzQ3ZjciLC=="
        },
        "connectVia": {
            "referenceName": "IR-FS-DEV",
            "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I use a similar approach and try connecting to a network drive,my connection is failing.

```
{
    "name": "NetworkDrive_LS",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
    "properties": {
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "FileServer",
        "typeProperties": {
            "host": "\\\\<host>:<port>\\SD\\AZURE_FS",
            "userId": "<userid>",
            "encryptedCredential": "eyJDcmVkZW50aWFsSW=="
        },
        "connectVia": {
            "referenceName": "ServerIR-VM",
            "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
        }
    } }
```

Also,I am using a Self Hosted IR. Is there something I am doing wrong? My error is as below :

File path `\\<host>:<port>\SD\AZURE_FS` is not supported. Check the configuration to make sure the path is valid. The given path's format is not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I found my mistake -

As per the example from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system)

```
{
    "name": "FileLinkedService",
    "properties": {
        "type": "FileServer",
        "typeProperties": {
            "host": "<host>",
            "userid": "<domain>\\<user>",
            "password": {
                "type": "SecureString",
                "value": "<password>"
            }
        },
        "connectVia": {
            "referenceName": "<name of Integration Runtime>",
            "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
        }
    }
}
```

I changed to add the domain for the userid and also removed the port number. That solved.

```
{
    "name": "NetworkDrive_LS",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
    "properties": {
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "FileServer",
        "typeProperties": {
            "host": "\\\\<host>\\SD\\AZURE_FS",
            "userId": "<domain>\\<user>",
            "encryptedCredential": "eyJDcmVkZW50aWFsSWQiOiIwY=="
        },
        "connectVia": {
            "referenceName": "ServerIR-VM",
            "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please mark it as answer, so it is helpful for others in future

Comment: Stackoverflow throws a message "You can accept your own answer in 2 days" when trying to mark it as an answer. Hence unable to change. I guess I need to wait for 2 days.